# Ошибка: from telebot import types from os import getenv SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

Возникла проблема! Решил скачать исходник бота с гетхаба. Интересно было как это устроено и как работают бота! И вот возникла такая вот проблема! Выбивает ошибку:

```
File "C:\Users\COMP\PycharmProjects\MUSICROBOT\-MUSIC-I-D-R-BOT-\main.py", line 9
    from telebot import types from os import getenv
SyntaxError: invalid syntax                              ^^^^
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно решить такую проблему??

Comment: Что такое `typesfrom`?

Comment: @VZSPB Кстати, на будущее, надо писать не "гетхаб", а "гитхаб".

Answer (score 2):

В `typesfrom` между s и f нажми на Enter.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо!

Comment: Отметьте этот ответ как [**принятый**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (галка напротив ответа).